# Is there a modern model text editor ?

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor

I have used VSCode, Sublime and Atom, but i heard of a editor where i can use only keyboard - Vim. When I installed it I was quiet shocked. It was a command line editor. Is there a modal code editor, that is a program (not a command line text editor) with good visuals.

Comment: Did you try `gvim`?

Comment: Thank you. I think that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim comes in two incarnations: as a command-line application that runs in the terminal, and a GUI version, launched with `gvim`, `vim -g`, or even from inside terminal Vim via `:gui`.

The "graphical" GVIM will still look a lot like the terminal version, but you get more available colors, additional highlighting attributes like undercurl, and some more keys to map. The idea is that both can be used interchangably and offer similar features. Cp. `:help design-not`:

> - Vim is not a fancy GUI editor that tries to look nice at the cost of
>     being less consistent over all platforms.  But functional GUI features are
>     welcomed.

#### Alternatives

There's [neovim](https://neovim.io/), a modern drop-in replacement, as well as some other vi clones. Emacs supports mode-based editing via the [Evil mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil).